# How to model per user state in a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails podcast catcher and I can't figure out how to model per user episode state.

I'd like to have a model that includes information about an episode, and whether the user has played the episode or what they have rated it.

The table would look like this:

```
episodes_1
id | user_id | podcast_id | title | audio_url | duration| is_played | rating
```

If many users were subscribed to the same podcasts there would be many records with the same
title and audio_url, so I thought of another table representation:

```
episodes_2
id | podcast_id | title | audio_url | duration

user_episode_data
id | user_id | episode_id | is_played | rating
```

If you joined `user_episode_data` with `episodes_2` on `user_episode_data.episode_id = episode_2.id` you would get a table with all of the information in `episodes_1`

The second choice seems like a better way to store the data, but the first seems like a better way to present the data.

Is is possible to use multiple tables to store a model?

```
class Podcast < AcitiveRecord::Base
  has_many :episodes
end

class Episode < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :podcast
  has_many :user_episode_datas
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :podcast
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_may :subscriptions
  has_may :podcasts, through: :subscriptions
  has_may :episodes, through :podcasts
  has_many :user_episode_datas
end

class UserEpisodeData < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :episode
end
```

I'd like `user.episodes` to return the collection of all episodes for each podcast they are subscribed to, and I'd like `user.episodes.first.is_played` to return true if that user has played that episode, but the episode model doesn't belong to any user, so I don't know how to model a one to one relationship between episode and user_episode_data in rails

Comment: You've completely changed the nature of your question by interjecting an interceding `Subscription` model. This is frustrating for those trying to help, to say the least. It may behoove you (and help procure better answers) in the future to be more upfront with these types of requirements.

Comment: I don't think adding the subscription model changed what I originally meant, or the nature of my question, but it does make my question more clear. I realise that I'm not expressing my self very well.

Comment: You original question didn't cite the `Subscription` model a _single_ time – and yes, it does materially change the question, because there are now two intermediaries, rather than one. Accordingly, the relationships between models need to be completely redrawn. I was just making a suggestion, at any rate. No need to rehash this point any further.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to set up these relationships in the manner proposed. Instead, model `Episode` and `User` as a `has_many :through` relationship:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :views
  has_many :episodes, through: :views
end

class View < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :episode
end

class Episode < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :views
  has_many :users, through: :views
end
```

The canonical Rails guide [provides an explanation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) of an example that very closely mirrors the scenario you've depicted. Here's what it has to say about `has_many :through` relationships:

> A has_many :through association is often used to set up a many-to-many connection with another model. This association indicates that the declaring model can be matched with zero or more instances of another model by proceeding through a third model.

Note that, in the example above, the `View` model effectively acts as the join table. If you want to add attributes to the relationship between an `Episode` and a `User` – `has_played` or `rating`, for instance – you would add those attributes to the `View` model.

Comment: If an episode doesn't have a view it won't be included in the user.episodes collection.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Is that the behavior you want to mimic?